# How were number symbols derived/shaped up?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

This question was sitting on my *to do* list for sometime.
So, as I was reading a book on history of science, I came across of a paragraph where the author attempted to give a historical development about "how we got the symbols that we use today for the numbers 1 to 9?"

He started with `1` saying that humans would represent `1` with a stick on the ground which eventually has been drawn, let's say, in the sand, and reached us in the form we know it.

Next, `2` was represented with two horizontal sticks (ex: =) and, by drawing it, the fast hand connected the right end of the upper stick with the beginning of the left end of the lower stick, giving as the `2` that we know.

Something with `3`...`3` parallel sticks...fast hand drawing transformed it into our `3`. And that's where the author stopped the story!

Does anyone know the rest of the story for the rest of the symbols, if there is one?

PS: Feel free to change the title of the post if you think that is not suggestive enough!

Comment: This "origin theory" is completely made up, even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals#History) gives a more accurate account. The original Indian symbols looked different, and their adaptations by Arabs produced multiple variations, none of them related to stick shapes or some other pictorial ideas.

Comment: A good book may help, see K.Menninger, [Number Words and Number Symbols: A Cultural History of Numbers](https://books.google.it/books?id=RXbCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score -2):

It's easy to see that 1, 2 & 3 represent these numbers. In fact, this is so obvious a way to represent numbers that both Egyptian hieratic - from which our system of representing numbers came from - and Chinese *xiaoxie* numerals use the same symbols.

However, the eye doesn't easily distinguish higher numbers of parallel strokes and hence it made sense to change how we represent the higher numbers because of counting the strokes, which takes time, we merely recognise the symbol. In the Egyptian hieratic they do this at five and higher, whilst in Chinese *xiaoxie*, it's at four and higher; it's likely that these came out through trial and error and also tradition, once it set in.

Comment: This is interesting.  However, answers with references are better than "easy to see" or "it's likely" answers.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: with the ubiquity of search engines I don't tend to bother with references.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah with the ubiquity of unreliable information HSM doesnt tend to bother with people who dont provide references

Comment: @Sam Gallagher: You've dropped the apostrophe in 'doesnt' and 'dont'. It's a little ironic that you're speaking of unreliability.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Welcome to the subtle difference between being formal and being reliable

Comment: @sam gallagher: Your subtleties are lost on me. My reputation is high because people trust that my posts have reliable information. My time is my time and not Stack Exchange's. And if you haven't noticed - they don't pay people for their time.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Comments are for discussing answers, if you would like to explain yourself please do so in a chat or on Meta. As for the answer, and there is nothing wrong with leaving out references on many StackExchange sites. But, as you should know, HSM does prefer the use of cited material. You are not obligated to provide references, or even answers. But you did, and Gerald Edgar gave you some criticism and your answer has been downvoted slightly. The quality of your answer will speak for itself; its rating may improve if references or concrete information are added, so consider doing so.

Comment: @Sam Gallagher: I've been on SE to know what the 'rules' are. My reputation speaks for itself - as yours does.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You care very much about reputation, but apparently not as much about giving good useful answers. You are on a history stack exchange. The answer you provided does not provide any historical evidence. It is therefore not a good answer. If you follow me so far, then either update your answer, leave it alone and take the downvotes, or remove it. Otherwise, keep digging yourself into this hole, trying to throw insults at me, and defending your reputation. I don't care about you, or your reputation. It's a meaningless 'internet points' figure as far as I'm concerned. Figure it out.

Comment: @sam gallagher: I rarely mention reputation. What I'm pointing out is that I'm not impressed with your platitudes.